# clearRect of canvas context does not clear the pixels

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to make an animation with javascript and html canvas, just the make a rectangle move from the top of the window to the bottom, I use canvas.clearRect to clear all the pixel on the canvas, but, it seems this function does not work, the previously drawing was still there. here is all the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <title>Jave script tetris by zdd</title>
    <head>
        <script>
            function point(x, y)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }

            function draw(timeDelta)
            {
                // Vertices to draw a square
                var v1 = new point(  0,   0);
                var v2 = new point(100,   0);
                var v3 = new point(100, 100);
                var v4 = new point(  0, 100);
                this.vertices = [v1, v2, v3, v4];

                // Get canvas context
                var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var cxt = c.getContext("2d");

                // Clear the canvas, this does not work?
                cxt.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

                // Move the piece based on time elapsed, just simply increase the y-coordinate here
                for (var i = 0; i < this.vertices.length; ++i)
                {
                    this.vertices[i].y += timeDelta;
                }

                cxt.moveTo(this.vertices[0].x, this.vertices[0].y);
                for (var i = 1; i < this.vertices.length; ++i)
                {
                    cxt.lineTo(this.vertices[i].x, this.vertices[i].y);
                }
                cxt.lineTo(this.vertices[0].x, this.vertices[0].y);
                cxt.stroke();
            }

            var lastTime = Date.now();
            function mainLoop()
            {
                window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                                               window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                               window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                                               window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
                window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

                var currentTime = Date.now();
                var timeDelta = (currentTime - lastTime);
                draw(timeDelta);
                lastTime = currentTime;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
        </canvas>
        <script>
        </script>
        <button type="button" style="position:absolute; left:500px; top:600px; width:100px; height:50px;" class="start" onclick="mainLoop()">start</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the result picture in Chrome, I want only one rectangle, but the clearRect function didn't clear the old rectangle, so..., how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: since you are already calling 'context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);' - is there any error in the console?

Comment: @nycynik, Have you see my code? I have that in the draw function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `beginPath`.  Without it each box is actually part of the last box.

```
    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.moveTo(this.vertices[0].x, this.vertices[0].y);

    for (var i = 1; i < this.vertices.length; ++i) {
        cxt.lineTo(this.vertices[i].x, this.vertices[i].y);
    }
```

after adding that, the box seems to jiggle around, not sure if thats your intention.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6xbQN/

Good luck!

Comment: That's not ture, it's nothing with beginPath.

Comment: after i add it, I no longer see the multiple boxes.  Have you tried it?  Why does it not work?

Comment: can you be clear about does not work?  You mean you still see the multiple boxes?  Here is the fiddle, you can clearly see just one animated box.  http://jsfiddle.net/6xbQN/  I think you have a whole other problem related to the movement of the box, and timedelta.

Comment: I still see multiple box on my computer.